# How do I start pdb and step into a function from the REPL?

Tags: python, debugging

I want to know how Python executes `inspect.signature`, so I want to step into this function call `inspect.signature(bytes.__getitem__)`. One way to do that is to write a file with these contents

```
import inspect

breakpoint()
inspect.signature(bytes.__getitem__)
```

and then run it and use the `s` pdb command to step into the function call.

My question is, can I do this from the REPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by importing `pdb` and then calling your function using either [`pdb.runcall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.runcall):

```py
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.runcall(signature, bytes.__getitem__)
> /usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py(3118)signature()
-> return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
(Pdb)
```

or [`pdb.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.run):

```py
>>> pdb.run("signature(bytes.__getitem__)")
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py(3116)signature()
-> def signature(obj, *, follow_wrapped=True):
(Pdb)
```